# Point of intersection of pair of straight lines

Tags: partial-derivative, coordinate-systems

We have our general equation is second degree in two variables:
$ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$

Let's say this represents a pair of straight lines

Our professor told that we could find the point of intersection by partially differentiating it twice, once with x and once with y and solve those 2 equations.

$2ax+2hy+2g=0$

$2hx+2by+2f=0$

I don't really understand how partial derivative of the equation has any significance here. Why is this true? What do the partially differentiated equations represent?

Comment: The above equation can be written as $(a_1x+b_1y+c_1)(a_2x+b_2y+c_2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the two lines given to us are $L(x,y)=0$ and $J(x,y)=0$, where $L(x,y)=px+qy+r$ and $J(x,y)=sx+ty+z$.  Then the equation of the pairs of these lines is
$$LJ=0. \tag{1}$$
Let us consider the line given by
$$L+\lambda J=0. \tag{2}$$
For different values of $\lambda$, we will get a line that passes through the intersection of the lines $L$ and $J$. The only point $(x,y)$ for which (2) will have a solution for **every** $\lambda$ is when $(x,y)$ is the intersection of the lines $L$ and $J$.

Coming back to equation (1), if we take the partial derivative with regards to $x$ and $y$, then we get
\begin{align*}
L_x\, J+J_x \, L & =0\\
L_y\, J+J_y \, L & =0.
\end{align*}
Note that $L_x,L_y,J_x,J_y$ are all constants (real numbers). Suppose say $J_x, J_y \neq 0$, then we can divide by $J_x$ and $J_y$ to get
\begin{align*}
L +\lambda_1 J & =0\\
L +\lambda_2 J & =0.
\end{align*}
Which is basically in the form of equation (2). So a common solution for this system will give us the solution for equation (2) that can work for all values of $\lambda$, and hence the intersection point.

Comment: Great! I never knew it was secretly related to the family itself! Thanks